# How to understand extended entities in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony, extend

I have a project where I would like to have three different kind of "customers".

- BaseCustomer

  - firstName
  - lastName
  - email
  - phone
- Customer extends BaseCustomer

  - streetName
  - streetNo
  - zipcode
  - city
- Member extends Customer

  - memberNo

I know how to setup the single entities with orm/tables etc. But my knowledge fails when it comes to extending the entities.

What is the best practice about extending entities when I also need to implement mysql (inno) tables?

Comment: I found the way for me regarding this. The Single Table inheritance is what I needed. 

**One important thing for other php oop newbies:** I forgot to set the properties of the BaseCustomer and Customer to protected instead of private. That gave me a lot of headache. :-(

Once that was changed it all worked nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with Doctrine its inheritance mapping is what you're looking for:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

You can choose from MappedSuperclasses, Single or Class Table Inheritance. 
The different pro's and con's are listed and it's depending on your situation (and other entities which might be related to your customer objects).

Comment: Thank you - I'll have a look at "Class Table Inheritance" as it seems to be the one I'm looking for.